# Add fadein before my primary css animation

Tags: css, animation, fadein

I would like to add a FadeIn with CSS on #loader before my animation but it doesn't work.
You can test it here : http://codepen.io/AntoinePlu/pen/yLvdi

Any idea why ?

There is my HTML :

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <ul id="loader">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And here my CSS :

```
body{background-color:#39414D;}

#wrapper {
  margin: 5% auto;
  display:block;
  width:300px;
}
#loader{
    margin: auto;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    list-style:none;
}

#loader li{
  background-color:#ffffff;
  width:8px;
  height:40px;
  float:left;
  margin-right:6px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  -webkit-animation: fadein 4s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to   { opacity: 1; }
}


@-webkit-keyframes insights {
    0%{
        height: 10px;
     margin-top: 90px;
    }

    50%{
        height: 50px;
     margin-top: 50px;
    }
    100%{
        height: 10px;
     margin-top: 90px;
    }
}

#loader li:nth-child(1){
  -webkit-animation: insights 1s ease-in-out infinite -0.8s;
}
#loader li:nth-child(2){
  -webkit-animation: insights 1s ease-in-out infinite -0.6s;
}
#loader li:nth-child(3){
  -webkit-animation: insights 1s ease-in-out infinite -0.4s;
}
#loader li:nth-child(4){
  -webkit-animation: insights 1s ease-in-out infinite -0.2s;
}
#loader li:nth-child(5){
  -webkit-animation: insights 1s ease-in-out infinite 0;
}
```

Thanks for you answer!

Comment: Fadein ? with what page,body,content?

Comment: Fadein on my loader content when my DOM is ready but without JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of `@-webkit-keyframes 'fadein'` and `@-webkit-keyframes 'insights'` write

`@-webkit-keyframes fadein` and `@-webkit-keyframes insights`

wrong syntx, no need for `''` in your code

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xjuyn

Comment: I've found my error, just need to move "-webkit-animation: fadein 4s;" in #Loader. 
It works well now !

http://codepen.io/AntoinePlu/pen/yLvdi